# Fetch data from local Next API in getStaticProps in Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm fetching data in `getStaticProps()` in Next js and this works fine in local development but generates an error in `next build` as the server isn't available while in `next build`

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/cs failed, 
reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

After reading some discussions on GitHub, came to know that you cannot use fetch directly in getStaticProps. So I then separated the fetch logic into separate file and call the the function inside the `getStaticProps`. Here's the code..

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const data = await getData(params.id);

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { id: "cs" } },
      { params: { id: "hyd" } },
      { params: { id: "cass" } },
    ],
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

and the `getData` code is in another file

```
export async function getData(id){
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${id}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    return data
}
```

This code works in local development, but generates errors while in `next build` that the connection is refused as the server isn't available while in build mode. So I made the server run in another terminal, but this generates an error on the WriteStream instance.

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\next-project\next-website\.next\trace'
Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)    
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\next-project\\next-website\\.next\\trace' 
}
```

I can fetch the data from client side but wanted to try the `getStaticProps` as the no of pages are just 3.  What's the correct way to fetch the local next API to build a static page.

**Edit**: adding API endpoint
file: `api/cs`

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({
    headerText:
      "Page Header text",
    joinText:
      "Some text",
    benefits: [
      {
        src: "/cs/photo-1.webp",
        text: "Some text",
      },
      {
        src: "/cs/photo-2.webp",
        text: "some text",
      },

    ],
    advisor: {
      name: "Name",
      email: "person-email",
      linkedin: "https://www.linkedin.com/in/person",
    },
    advisorMsg:
      "Some text",
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do Not Fetch an API Route from getStaticProps or getStaticPaths You
> should not fetch an API Route from getStaticProps or getStaticPaths.
> Instead, write your server-side code directly in getStaticProps or
> getStaticPaths (or call a helper function).
>
> Here’s why: getStaticProps and getStaticPaths run only on the
> server-side and will never run on the client-side. Moreover, these
> functions will not be included in the JS bundle for the browser. That
> means you can write code such as direct database queries without
> sending them to browsers. Read the Writing Server-Side code
> documentation to learn more.

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/api-routes/api-routes-details

So don't fetch data from the local API route in the getData function. Fetch it from where the API route fetches it.

Comment: Fetch it from where the API route fetches it. Could you elaborate on this.

Comment: The API route doesn't fetch the data from an external file or api. The api endpoint returns a json object. I will attach that file for reference in the question.

Comment: You can move (copy/paste) the json into getData function

UPD Or move it into a variable and use in the both places

Comment: this guy seems to have no problem fetching localhost from `getStaticProps` https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrmndNpWSJw